# Why does Angular Material set background colors?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I just started using Angular Material (I am used to Bootstrap) and am noticing some strange things.  I am using the library for the `md-datepicker`, however, when I placed it on my page I noticed they were setting a background color to the picker:

```
md-datepicker.md-default-theme, md-datepicker {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

But my background for my site is a blue color, so there is just a white box floating on top of the datepicker and it looks terrible. Why would they even set this value in the first place? Why not leave it transparent so it can be used with any site and any background color?

This just seems to make my life harder because now I have to go override those styles in my CSS.

Can someone please explain why Google would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a library that appeases every conceivable design requirement I believe is a very tall order.

That is what makes the web so amazing, everything is open-source and you can hack it as much as you like, until it looks exactly the way you want it.

But you don't have to be a hardcore source code digger to change what you need, that is why the Angular-material library comes with a .scss file (Sass mixin) that compiles into the css libraries for you.

If you got angular-material with bower there is a angular-material.scss file which you can edit and then can re-compile, the line number you looking for is around 2615:

```
// Floating pane that contains the calendar at the bottom of the input.
.md-datepicker-calendar-pane {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: $z-index-menu;

  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  background: transparent;

  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform $md-datepicker-open-animation-duration $swift-ease-out-timing-function;

  &.md-pane-open {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to why is because Angular Material is based on Material Design which has very specific color guidelines implemented in Angular Material via the concept of themes. To control your background color you can use CSS and you can also configure your theme. This topic has details on the use of themes: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme.